# Speed up slow filtering page in SQL Server and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, query-optimization

Let’s say we have a table with information about our clients with almost 3 million rows and over 80 columns including a lot of `nvarchar(max)`.

In our ASP.NET MVC Web App we have a page that allows users to navigate through this table with various filtering, ordering and pagination. Filtering and sorting can be performed on 20 different columns with some of them requiring subqueries to other tables. All filtering/sorting queries are also auto generated by Entity Framework 6 and only select the primary key (PK) column (later by PK we extract other required columns with different request).

Our filter UI looks like this:

[image: filter UI]

Most filtering combination work fine, but some of them are known to be extremely slow (over 30 seconds when others take less than a second). One of the reasons for this behavior is that for some combinations of filters MS SQL is choosing a bad execution plan with not appropriate indexes (instead of choosing index on `WHERE` clause it takes index for `ORDER BY` clause and performs index scan with key lookups). For example, instead of using `ManagerId` index and performing an index seek this auto-generated query uses `Date` index and performs an index scan.

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Clients] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Paid] <> 1) AND ((([Extent1].[ManagerId] IN (N'd3cbce41-1db3-4b6d-8a14-1d5704090b3d')) AND ([Extent1].[ManagerId] IS NOT NULL)) 
OR ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Partners] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[ClientId]) AND ([Extent2].[PartnerId] IN (N'd3cbce41-1db3-4b6d-8a14-1d5704090b3d'))
)))
ORDER BY row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Date] ASC)
OFFSET 600 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

For another example, query with 6 different filtering options selected might look like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project11].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Date1] AS [Date1]
    FROM [dbo].[Clients] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Paid] <> 1) 
    AND ((([Extent1].[ManagerId] IN (N''73cdda41-0086-4104-a4c2-4dd59c306s14'', N''d9dfb477-6f56-47de-b73e-0a419f575a00'')) AND ([Extent1].[ManagerId] IS NOT NULL)) 
        OR (([Extent1].[SecondManagerId] IN (N''73cdda41-0086-4104-a4c2-4dd59c306s14'', N''d9dfb477-6f56-47de-b73e-0a419f575a00'')) AND ([Extent1].[SecondManagerId] IS NOT NULL))) 
    AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            [Extent2].[Code] AS [Code]
            FROM [dbo].[Codes] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[ClientId]
        INTERSECT
            SELECT 
            [UnionAll2].[C1] AS [C1]
            FROM  (SELECT 
                N''9.7'' AS [C1]
                FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
            UNION ALL
                SELECT 
                N''9.8'' AS [C1]
                FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]
            UNION ALL
                SELECT 
                N''9.9'' AS [C1]
                FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable3]) AS [UnionAll2]) AS [Intersect1]
    )) 
    AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable4]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            3 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable5]) AS [UnionAll3]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Stage] = [UnionAll3].[C1]
    )) 
    AND ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[Date1], 102) ,  102)) >= (convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), @p__linq__0, 102) ,  102))) 
    AND ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[Date1], 102) ,  102)) <= (convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), @p__linq__1, 102) ,  102))) 
    AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Table2] AS [Extent3]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent3].[ClientId]) 
            AND (0 = [Extent3].[Status]) 
            AND ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent3].[Date2], 102) ,  102)) >= (convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), @p__linq__2, 102) ,  102))) 
            AND ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent3].[Date2], 102) ,  102)) <= (convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), @p__linq__3, 102) ,  102)))
    ))
)  AS [Project11]
ORDER BY row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project11].[Date1] ASC)
OFFSET 1000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY ',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 datetime2(7),@p__linq__2 datetime2(7),@p__linq__3 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='2022-12-16 00:00:00',@p__linq__1='2022-12-18 00:00:00',@p__linq__2='2022-08-01 00:00:00',@p__linq__3='2022-12-15 00:00:00'
```

For some filtering options query has to make subqueries for other tables due to the many to many relationships between them.

We already have a separate index for almost every attribute (except `nvarchar(max)` ones) that being part of this filtering query but it’s not enough. Obviously, we cannot make a covering index for every filtering/ordering combination so we are currently considering making nonclustered columnstore index (NCCI) that would cover all this attributes combination. But one thing that worries us about this idea is that the table is being updated quite frequently (about 8000 – 15000 rows per day).

Are there any others approaches that we should look at to make this page fast for every filter combination? Like some external tools, libraries or methods. Or would the idea of using NCCI for our table work just fine?

Comment: "instead of choosing index on WHERE clause it takes index for ORDER BY clause and performs index scan with key lookups" - this would be a problem: ` AND ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[Date1], 102) ,  102)) >= (convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), @p__linq__0, 102) ,  102))) 
    AND ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[Date1], 102) ,  102)) <= (convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), @p__linq__1, 102) ,  102))) 
    `. Whenever a function is used on the column index cannot be used for that column.

Comment: The above looks like an EF problem to me. Try searching for "EF datetime2 unnecessary string conversions in generated SQL" in your favorite search engine.

Comment: If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.

Comment: Not a single response from OP to any of the comments or answers is puzzling.

Answer (score 2):

### Intro

To answer your question the db should be analyzed, below I will give you some of my considerations.

First of all your sentences:

#### First

> MS SQL is choosing a bad execution plan with not appropriate indexes
> (instead of choosing index on WHERE clause it takes index for ORDER BY
> clause and performs index scan with key lookups).

MS SQL chooses the best plan with the info it has. If you have bad index statistics, bad index fragmentation, etc, MSSQL can't do much.

#### Second

> we are currently considering making nonclustered columnstore index (NCCI)

From [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16#how-do-i-choose-between-a-rowstore-index-and-a-columnstore-index):

*Rowstore indexes perform best on queries that seek into the data, when searching for a particular value, or for queries on a small range of values. Use rowstore indexes with transactional workloads because they tend to require mostly table seeks instead of table scans.*

*Columnstore indexes give high performance gains for analytic queries that scan large amounts of data, especially on large tables. Use columnstore indexes on data warehousing and analytics workloads, especially on fact tables, because they tend to require full table scans rather than table seeks.*

From your question, you have row-level filtering, not aggregate (where columnstore are the best), from my point of view creating a columnstore is pointless.

### Considerations

From your question:

> But one thing that worries us about this idea is that the table is being >updated quite frequently (about 8000 – 15000 rows per day).

Based on this sentence some solutions below may not fit.

#### EntityFramework

Do you know how to write SQL queries? If the answer is yes, then use it, replace EF with Dapper (maybe with SqlKata or a similar fw) and write your own query.

EF does its best to write queries but it will never be like you who know the DB.

#### Index

**Always** check your query plans.

Do not add many indexes can be counterproductive, for every row added to the table the index must be updated.

If you have a column by which you can "partition" the table you can consider [table partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16)

Double-check your [statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-ver16).
if the query has *a good* index and bad plan check statistics.

#### Read-only database

Read-only databases are very fast for queries operations (they don't have to check for locking).

Consider [Database snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).

Consider a read-only [Replica](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver16)

#### Caching

You can use the [.NET MVC caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs)

You can use [Redis](https://redis.io/) or a similar software for caching.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach IMHO is to use a Stored Procedure (SP) with parameters for your query fields. These parameters can also be used to:

- Control the output, for example sort-order, top, etc.
- Submit multiple values by the use of [used-defined data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-user-defined-data-type-alias?view=sql-server-ver16)

The main advantages are:

- You, or your db-dev / dba, have full control of the query that is made
- Freedom of using sub queries in the SP
- Maintenance and optimization can be done without updating the ASP.NET MVC web app

In code I've come across I saw stuff like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [yourSchema].[GetYourData]
   @DateTimeFrom DATETIME = NULL,
   @DateTimeTill DATETIME = NULL,
   @SortAscending AS BIT = 0, -- control the output
   @ApplicationName VARCHAR(64) = NULL,
   @MachineName VARCHAR(256) = NULL,
   @UserName VARCHAR(256) = NULL,
   @MaxRowCount INT = 1000, -- control the output
   @KeyValueTable AS CustomTableType.KeyValueTable READONLY, -- submit a table to filter
   @SeverityTable AS CustomTableType.SeverityTable READONLY  -- submit a table to filter
AS
/* etc... */
```

You can call this SP from EF, but you also could use Dapper as suggested earlier by @Max.

Comment: I second this approach... it gives you full control and allows you to tune specific searches as required. I've done something similar in the past with good results.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK I’ve seen turning slow EF generated queries into blazing fast but overall controllable output a dozen times

Answer (score -1):

3 mil rows shouldn't be a huge problem so something's definitely wrong.
I'd concentrate on a couple of things:

1. Don't use auto-generated queries
2. Remove casts - those are unindexable
3. ORDER BY row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project11].[Date1] ASC) -- why not just order by date1? Row_number often needs to be completely materialized which is a bit unnecessary
4. Check your indexes, perhaps some fields can be added as INCLUDE, especially if you always search on X, but often also search on Y.
5. Try OPTION (RECOMPILE) to force plan regeneration
6. Run your queries with SET STATISTICS IO ON. Is there a lot of "action" on unexpected tables, maybe something is wrong there
7. See if you can create a indexable view with some of those joins pre-made which might simplify your WHERE conditions
8. Analyze the combinations that aren't using indexes. Test-run these with actual values and not dynamic parametrized SQL, are the results "better"? This could lead to #9.
9. Remove parametrized query and just input the values "raw". I know it's often suggested that parametrized queries are better, but since you have such varied queries, the selectivity might be mightly different, so the parameterizing can lead to bad query plans. Of course you gotta sanitize the data since it's coming from the web. Note, don't try this unless you absolutely cannot get it to work fast otherwise and actually have proper ability to sanitize the stuff, or you might leak data / end up on dailywtf

Answer (score -1):

Your can replace all that stuff by a series of light queries combined by EXCEPT, INTERSECT or UNION.

Those light queries will have a structure like:

```
SELECT Id
FROM   dbo.clients
WHERE  ... --> only one member predicate always "sargable" (avoid NOT, <> and OR...)
```

As an example for Query 1:

```
(
SELECT Id
FROM   dbo.Clients 
WHERE  ManagerId IN (N'd3cbce41-1db3-4b6d-8a14-1d5704090b3d')

INTERSECT

SELECT Id
FROM   dbo.Clients
WHERE  ManagerId IS NOT NULL 

UNION ALL

SELECT  Id
FROM    dbo.Clients AS C
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.Partners AS P
              WHERE C.Id = P.ClientId AND P.PartnerId IN (N'd3cbce41-1db3-4b6d-8a14-1d5704090b3d'))
)

EXCEPT

SELECT Id
FROM   dbo.Clients 
WHERE  Paid = 1;
```

Why?

When using non sargable predicate the cardinality estimation can be very bad. So replace:

- <> by = with a EXCEPT set based operation
- OR by an UNION set based operation

Then all statistics for the optimizer will be accurate and the final execution plan will be good enough...